# Calculate length of repeats along a vector in r

Tags: r

Is there an efficient way to calculate the length of portions of a vector that repeat a specified value?
For instance, I want to calculate the length of rainless periods along a vector of daily rainfall values:

```
daily_rainfall=c(15, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 10)
```

Besides using the obvious but clunky approach of looping through the vector, what cleaner way can I get to the desired answer of

```
rainless_period_length=c(3, 2)
```

given the vector above?

Comment: Our old friend `?rle` is what you are looking for - run-length-encoding - very close to a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936958/get-length-of-runs-of-missing-values-in-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R has a built-in function `rle`: "run-length encoding":

```
daily_rainfall <- c(15, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 10)

runs <- rle(daily_rainfall)
rainless_period_length <- runs$lengths[runs$values == 0]

rainless_period_length
```

output:

```
[1] 3 2
```

Comment: Beautiful! Added to my arsenal!